# How to retrieve first option value in dropdown list data

Tags: php, mysql, loops

Quite complicated to explain entirely but simply put, I require to add in dummy data into an existing item through a form consisting of:

*Note: This is a form so basically it goes like this

"Product Information"

- Part number - 'dummy'
- Serial number - 'dummy'
- Description - 'dummy'

This 3 fields above are in text field.

And here's another field which I have issues to display result.

Wish to achieve:

- Item category - 'Desktop'

*Desktop is option value = '1'

> Here is my coding. Firstly, just a category option check:

```
foreach($resultCatAdd as &$value) {
    if ($value == "Product Information") {
        $checkProduct = true;
    } elseif ($value == "Warranty Information") {
        $checkWarranty = true;
    } 
}
```

> Followed by looping the two categories and include an add SQL to
>   insert the dummy data:

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM einv_asset WHERE einv_asset_stockrm  = '" . $code . "';";

    $get_einv_asset_stockrm_SQL = base_executeSQL($SQL);
    while($Asset_row = base_fetch_array($get_einv_asset_stockrm_SQL))  
    if (base_num_rows($get_einv_asset_stockrm_SQL)!= 0)
{

// Product Information Category
        if ($checkProduct == true) {

            if(einv_checkStockrmCat($Asset_row['einv_asset_code'],"Product") == false)
            {
                $addProductSQL="INSERT INTO einv_product_information (einv_pinfo_pn,einv_pinfo_serial,einv_pinfo_desc,einv_pinfo_itemcat,einv_pinfo_aid)
                VALUES ('dummy','dummy','dummy','1','" . $Asset_row['einv_asset_code'] . "')";

            if(!base_executeSQL($addProductSQL)){
                $continue = false;
                echo $addProductSQL;
            }else { $continue = true; }

            }
        }


        // Warranty Information Category
        if ($checkWarranty == true) {

            if(einv_checkStockrmCat($Asset_row['einv_asset_code'],"Warranty") == false)
            {
                $addWarrantySQL="INSERT INTO einv_warranty_information (einv_winfo_wstart,einv_winfo_wend,einv_winfo_wrt,einv_winfo_aid)
                VALUES ('".date('d/m/Y',strtotime("now"))."','".date('d/m/Y', strtotime('now -1 day +1 year'))."','1','" . $Asset_row['einv_asset_code'] . "')";

            if(!base_executeSQL($addWarrantySQL)){
                $continue = false;
                echo $addWarrantySQL;
            }else { $continue = true; }

            }
        }
```

> From the coding as above, I am able to retrieve my values such as:

1. einv_pinfo_pn or Part Number[**text field**] - value : 'dummy'

This could be retrieved and shown in my form.

However,

2. einv_pinfo_itemcat or Item Category[**dropdown field**] - value : '1' = 'Desktop'

This could not be retrieved and nothing is shown.

How do I go about to retrieve this result?

How do I make that sql to retrieve the **first option value** of item category that is available from the **Database**? (which will be my Desktop or '1')